# Storing global array in session storage

Tags: html, json, local-storage

I'm aiming to store a global array in session storage. I know to do so you have to stringify the array and than later parse it to retrieve it. I added an alert function to let the user see if the array was stored successfully or not. I'm getting an alert on my retrieve() function that says the array is undefined. I know that this is because my store() function is not right, but I'm not sure where I screwed up. The array works on it's own so I don't think the problem lies in that. My function to store is:

```
  //================================================================
// storeInventory
//================================================================
function storeInventoryArray()
{
  localStorage.setItem("InventoryArray",
    JSON.stringify(InventoryArray));
  alert("Inventory items stored.");


}

 <body class="main" onload="storeInventoryArray()">
```

Comment: You're right. I need to remove it as it was something I added before trying to retrieve the function in a different page, but I'm still not receiving an alert that items were removed nor stored from the store().

Comment: So, [edit] your question to show your real code, because looking to what you show us now, it makes no sense, so we can't help. Take a look here [mcve]

Comment: Based on edit now: you call `storeInventoryArray` when body loads, but when and how the variable `InventoryArray` is instantiated and setted? All I can think now is that it is being stored as undefined, since it doesn't exist when you store it